# Export large amount of data to Excel does not work

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, excel

MVC. I have a table in a web page, export to Excel does not work when table has over 1,000 rows, with 500 or less it works. This is the code:

```
var tableToExcel = (function () {
var uri = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,'
    , template = '<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>{worksheet}</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet></x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]--><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /></head><body><table>{table}</table></body></html>'
    , base64 = function (s) { return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s))) }
    , format = function (s, c) { return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function (m, p) { return c[p]; }) }
return function (table, name) {
    if (!table.nodeType) table = document.getElementById(table)
    var ctx = { worksheet: name || 'Worksheet', table: table.innerHTML }
    window.location.href = uri + base64(format(template, ctx))
}})()

$("#imgExcel").click(function () {
        tableToExcel('tblEquipment', 'Equipment');
    });
```

What is wrong?

Comment: Most browsers have a limit to how long a URL can be.  It's possible you are exceeding that limit.

Comment: Tim Williams the browser shows all rows without problem, when i push export button nothing happends

Comment: `window.location.href = uri + base64(format(template, ctx))`  If the string passed to `base64()` is too long then this will not succeed.  **EDIT** - on further reading the limit may be higher than I thought, but you should still investigate this possibility.  What browser are you using?

Comment: I am using Google Chrome, I think base64 has a limit and i need to find another way to export large amount of date